# Detect pause/resume in ExoPlayer

Tags: android, exoplayer, resume, pause

I searched two days for this question in [github](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues) but i can't find true answer . I want example for detecting `pause / resume` in `ExoPlayer > 2.x` . 
Any one can give me an example ? I checked `onPlayerStateChanged` and problem not solved .

```
onPlayerStateChanged   :   STATE_BUFFERING 
onPlayerStateChanged   :   STATE_READY
```

I just got this log from `onPlayerStateChanged` and this is not called in all times !

Answer (score 81, accepted):

EDIT---

Please refer to the `Player.isPlaying()` method which provides this as an API.

"Rather than having to check these properties individually, Player.isPlaying can be called."

https://exoplayer.dev/listening-to-player-events.html#playback-state-changes

--- EDIT END

You need to check `playWhenReady` with a [Player.EventListener](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/library/core/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/Player.java#L274). The [Playback states of ExoPlayer](http://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/doc/reference/constant-values.html#com.google.android.exoplayer2.Player.STATE_BUFFERING) are independent from the player being paused or not:

```
player.addListener(new Player.DefaultEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
    if (playWhenReady && playbackState == Player.STATE_READY) {
      // media actually playing
    } else if (playWhenReady) {
      // might be idle (plays after prepare()), 
      // buffering (plays when data available) 
      // or ended (plays when seek away from end)
    } else {
      // player paused in any state
    }
  }
});
```

To play/pause the player ExoPlayer provides

```
player.setPlayWhenReady(boolean)
```

The sequence of playback states with ExoPlayer with a media file which never stalls to rebuffer is once in each of the four states and does not express play/paused:

```
Player.STATE_IDLE;
Player.STATE_BUFFERING;
Player.STATE_READY;
Player.STATE_ENDED;
```

Each time the player needs to buffer it goes:

```
Player.STATE_READY;
Player.STATE_BUFFERING;
Player.STATE_READY;
```

Setting playWhenReady does not affect the state.

All together your media is actually playing when

```
playWhenReady && playbackState == Player.STATE_READY
```

It plays when ready. :)

Comment: The mentioned constants are marked deprecated now, but they are still working, which is useful for debugging.

Comment: On the dev-2 branch (prerelease) the STATE_XYZ constants are not deprecated. Why do you think this is the case?

Comment: I'm using Exo Player 2.7.0 and Android Studio tells me so (targeting API 27 and down to 16) - I just wanted to leave some info that they are still working. I'm not sure about the "dev-2 branch".

Comment: This logic fails when we pause video in landscape mode and change to portrait mode. Any solution for that?

Answer (score 17):

It must be that since the other answers were posted, a new method has been provided in Player.EventListener. [EDIT: Now it is Player.Listener, as Player.EventListener has been deprecated]. This works well for me:

```
override fun onIsPlayingChanged(isPlaying: Boolean) {
    // your code here
}
```

If isPlaying is false, it is paused, otherwise playing.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not triggered when the video ends

Answer (score 16):

You can use this function:

```
public boolean isPlaying() {
    return exoPlayer.getPlaybackState() == Player.STATE_READY && exoPlayer.getPlayWhenReady();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

> **I had the same requirement to detect the click event of exoplayer play/pause button. Above answers were mainly talking about the state not
>   about the button click event.**

This is what I did to detect the Play/Pause button click, works perfect.

**Step 1: Create custom control dispatcher class and override the method `dispatchSetPlayWhenReady`**

```
class PlayerControlDispatcher : DefaultControlDispatcher() {
    override fun dispatchSetPlayWhenReady(player: Player?, playWhenReady: Boolean): Boolean {
        if(playWhenReady) {
           // Play button clicked
        } else {
          // Paused button clicked
        }
        return super.dispatchSetPlayWhenReady(player, playWhenReady)
    }
}
```

**Step 2: Set the custom control dispatcher class `PlayerControlDispatcher` into the the player view.**

```
playerView.setControlDispatcher(PlayerControlDispatcher())
```

Where playerView is an instance of `com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView` which we declare in our layout file.

Comment: This is the correct answer, just works perfectly! Thank you @krishna-sharma!

Comment: Glad to see that it worked for you @renatoarg, it will help others to address this answer now.

Comment: Hi @KrishnaSharma I tried your code but got error. Could you explain where I should put the code location/position?

Comment: @HiDayurieDave you can put that anywhere, either create separate class or inner class. Important line is playerView.setControlDispatcher(PlayerControlDispatcher())

Comment: The ControlDispatcher interface has been removed in 2.16.0, see https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/releases/tag/r2.16.0.

Comment: binding.playerView.findViewById<View>(R.id.exo_play_pause).setOnClickListener {  }
this will also work to detect click events on play/pause button.

Answer (score 6):

**Kotlin 2020 solution approach UPDATE**

Events such as changes in state and playback errors are reported to registered `Player.EventListener` instances.

`Player.EventListener` **has empty default methods**, so you only need to implement the methods you’re interested in.

First your class, say your activity, **has to conform** to the `Player.EventListener` interface.

Then you override the `onIsPlayingChanged` method, on the class. *Outside `onCreate` method...*

Add the listener to your player instance:

```
// Adding player listener for tracking events
player?.addListener(this)
```

You can check if the player is playing (i.e. the position is advancing) with Player.isPlaying:

```
//Listening to player events
override fun onIsPlayingChanged(isPlaying: Boolean){
    if (isPlaying) {
        // Active playback.
    } else {
        // Not playing because playback is paused, ended, suppressed, or the player
        // is buffering, stopped or failed. Check player.getPlaybackState,
        // player.getPlayWhenReady, player.getPlaybackError and
        // player.getPlaybackSuppressionReason for details.
    }
}
```

That's it. Very simple.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `exoplayer.getPlayWhenReady()` to check whether the player is currently in a pause state or playing state.

Answer (score 2):

I think the callback:

```
fun onPlayWhenReadyChanged(playWhenReady: Boolean, reason: Int)
```

From the `Player.Listener`

Comment: Yes. It really worked for me! It is called only when the user plays or pauses the media.

Answer (score 2):

With version 2.16.1, I use this code:

```kotlin
exoPlayer.addListener(object : Player.Listener {
    override fun onIsPlayingChanged(isPlaying: Boolean) {
        if (isPlaying){
            videoIsPlaying()
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code snipped. The player listener(onPlayerStateChanged) isn't good to observe play / pause action its called multiple time and also invoke while player configuring.

```
videoView.setControlDispatcher(object : DefaultControlDispatcher() {
            override fun dispatchSetPlayWhenReady(player: Player, playWhenReady: Boolean): Boolean {
                if (playWhenReady)
                  // Tap on Play button  
                else
                 // Tap on Pause button
                return super.dispatchSetPlayWhenReady(player, playWhenReady)
            }
        })
```

Comment: The ControlDispatcher interface has been removed in 2.16.0, see github.com/google/ExoPlayer/releases/tag/r2.16.0.

Answer (score 0):

for kotlin

```kotlin
private fun ExoPlayer.isPlaying() =
    playbackState == Player.STATE_READY && playWhenReady
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use new version: `com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.18.6`

This function deprecated:

```kotlin
@Deprecated
    default void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, @State int playbackState) {}
```

New function is:

```kotlin
 default void onPlaybackStateChanged(@State int playbackState) {}
```

For example:

```kotlin
exoPlayer?.addListener(object : Player.Listener {
            override fun onPlaybackStateChanged(@Player.State state: Int) {
                when (state) {
                    Player.STATE_READY -> {
                        // The player is able to immediately play from its current position. The player will be playing if getPlayWhenReady() is true, and paused otherwise.
                    }
                    Player.STATE_BUFFERING -> {
                       // The player is not able to immediately play the media, but is doing work toward being able to do so. This state typically occurs when the player needs to buffer more data before playback can start.
                    }
                    Player.STATE_IDLE -> {
                       // The player is idle, meaning it holds only limited resources.The player must be prepared before it will play the media.
                    }
                    Player.STATE_ENDED -> { 
                       // The player has finished playing the media.
                    }
                    else -> {
                      // Other things
                    }
                }
            }
        })
```