# how to show notification with play/pause in exoplayer?

Tags: android, notifications, exoplayer

I am developing streaming application, so for that i am using exoplayer. This is the code.It is working everything fine.But I need to show notification along with title and play/pause button. This play/pause button must work like activity play/pause button and this play/pause button must change as per play/pause.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SimpleExoPlayer exoPlayer;

    private ExoPlayer.EventListener eventListener = new ExoPlayer.EventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimelineChanged(Timeline timeline, Object manifest) {
            Log.i(TAG,"onTimelineChanged");
        }

        @Override
        public void onTracksChanged(TrackGroupArray trackGroups, TrackSelectionArray trackSelections) {
            Log.i(TAG,"onTracksChanged");
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingChanged(boolean isLoading) {
            Log.i(TAG,"onLoadingChanged");
        }

        @Override
        public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
            Log.i(TAG,"onPlayerStateChanged: playWhenReady = "+String.valueOf(playWhenReady)
                    +" playbackState = "+playbackState);
            switch (playbackState){
                case ExoPlayer.STATE_ENDED:
                    Log.i(TAG,"Playback ended!");
                    //Stop playback and return to start position
                    setPlayPause(false);
                    exoPlayer.seekTo(0);
                    break;
                case ExoPlayer.STATE_READY:
                    Log.i(TAG,"ExoPlayer ready! pos: "+exoPlayer.getCurrentPosition()
                            +" max: "+stringForTime((int)exoPlayer.getDuration()));
                    setProgress();
                    break;
                case ExoPlayer.STATE_BUFFERING:
                    Log.i(TAG,"Playback buffering!");
                    break;
                case ExoPlayer.STATE_IDLE:
                    Log.i(TAG,"ExoPlayer idle!");
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {
            Log.i(TAG,"onPlaybackError: "+error.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onPositionDiscontinuity() {
            Log.i(TAG,"onPositionDiscontinuity");
        }
    };

    private SeekBar seekPlayerProgress;
    private Handler handler;
    private ImageButton btnPlay;
    private TextView txtCurrentTime, txtEndTime;
    private boolean isPlaying = false;

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        prepareExoPlayerFromURL(Uri.parse("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/musyc-f264f.appspot.com/o/Karone-Okarone-Minar-Rahman-Official-Music-Video-Eagle-Music.mp3?alt=media&token=a40ed28a-2970-4160-ac1d-33881e34253a"));
    }


    private void prepareExoPlayerFromURL(Uri uri){

        TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector();

        LoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl();

        exoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector, loadControl);

        DefaultDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, Util.getUserAgent(this, "exoplayer2example"), null);
        ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
        MediaSource audioSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(uri, dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);
        exoPlayer.addListener(eventListener);

        exoPlayer.prepare(audioSource);
        initMediaControls();
    }



    private void initMediaControls() {
        initPlayButton();
        initSeekBar();
        initTxtTime();
    }

    private void initPlayButton() {
        btnPlay = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
        btnPlay.requestFocus();
        btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                setPlayPause(!isPlaying);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Starts or stops playback. Also takes care of the Play/Pause button toggling
     * @param play True if playback should be started
     */
    private void setPlayPause(boolean play){
        isPlaying = play;
        exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(play);
        if(!isPlaying){
            btnPlay.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play);
        }else{
            setProgress();
            btnPlay.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause);
        }
    }

    private void initTxtTime() {
        txtCurrentTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time_current);
        txtEndTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.player_end_time);
    }

    private String stringForTime(int timeMs) {
        StringBuilder mFormatBuilder;
        Formatter mFormatter;
        mFormatBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        mFormatter = new Formatter(mFormatBuilder, Locale.getDefault());
        int totalSeconds =  timeMs / 1000;

        int seconds = totalSeconds % 60;
        int minutes = (totalSeconds / 60) % 60;
        int hours   = totalSeconds / 3600;

        mFormatBuilder.setLength(0);
        if (hours > 0) {
            return mFormatter.format("%d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds).toString();
        } else {
            return mFormatter.format("%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds).toString();
        }
    }

    private void setProgress() {
        seekPlayerProgress.setProgress(0);
        seekPlayerProgress.setMax((int) exoPlayer.getDuration()/1000);
        txtCurrentTime.setText(stringForTime((int)exoPlayer.getCurrentPosition()));
        txtEndTime.setText(stringForTime((int)exoPlayer.getDuration()));

        if(handler == null)handler = new Handler();
        //Make sure you update Seekbar on UI thread
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (exoPlayer != null && isPlaying) {
                    seekPlayerProgress.setMax((int) exoPlayer.getDuration()/1000);
                    int mCurrentPosition = (int) exoPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / 1000;
                    seekPlayerProgress.setProgress(mCurrentPosition);
                    txtCurrentTime.setText(stringForTime((int)exoPlayer.getCurrentPosition()));
                    txtEndTime.setText(stringForTime((int)exoPlayer.getDuration()));

                    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void initSeekBar() {
        seekPlayerProgress = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.mediacontroller_progress);
        seekPlayerProgress.requestFocus();

        seekPlayerProgress.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                if (!fromUser) {
                    // We're not interested in programmatically generated changes to
                    // the progress bar's position.
                    return;
                }

                exoPlayer.seekTo(progress*1000);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });

        seekPlayerProgress.setMax(0);
        seekPlayerProgress.setMax((int) exoPlayer.getDuration()/1000);

    }


}
```

I have tried many ways.
 [Music player control in notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23443946/music-player-control-in-notification)

[How to put media controller button on notification bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12526228/how-to-put-media-controller-button-on-notification-bar?noredirect=1&lq=1)

https://github.com/yalematta/ExoPlayback

but not working. So can any please help me how to do this, Thank you so much for your suggestion..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47731779/detect-pause-resume-in-exoplayer

Comment: Maybe this article can be useful for you
https://medium.com/google-exoplayer/playback-notifications-with-exoplayer-a2f1a18cf93b

Comment: thanks for your response. i am asking about notification and it's controls

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 9):

Basically, `ExoPlayer` provides a way for developers to tell the system that "I want to show player on the notification area". That is `PlayerNotificationManager`. Firstly, you need to add this declaration in the `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
```

And then, you can implement code as below:

```
private ExoPlayer exoPlayer;
private PlayerNotificationManager playerNotificationManager;
private int notificationId = 1234;
private PlayerNotificationManager.MediaDescriptionAdapter mediaDescriptionAdapter = new PlayerNotificationManager.MediaDescriptionAdapter() {
    @Override
    public String getCurrentSubText(Player player) {
        return "Sub text";
    }

    @Override
    public String getCurrentContentTitle(Player player) {
        return "Title";
    }

    @Override
    public PendingIntent createCurrentContentIntent(Player player) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getCurrentContentText(Player player) {
        return "ContentText";
    }

    @Override
    public Bitmap getCurrentLargeIcon(Player player, PlayerNotificationManager.BitmapCallback callback) {
        return null;
    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
    TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
    TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);
    exoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector);
    exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    playerNotificationManager = PlayerNotificationManager.createWithNotificationChannel(this, "My_channel_id", R.string.channel_name, notificationId, mediaDescriptionAdapter, new PlayerNotificationManager.NotificationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onNotificationPosted(int notificationId, Notification notification, boolean ongoing) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onNotificationCancelled(int notificationId, boolean dismissedByUser) {
        }
    });
    playerNotificationManager.setPlayer(exoPlayer);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (playerNotificationManager != null) {
        playerNotificationManager.setPlayer(null);
    }
    if (exoPlayer != null) {
        exoPlayer.release();
        exoPlayer = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Cao Manh Quang, should we do same process when we update notification content?

Comment: why it's annotated with @UnstableApi? isn't there a stable api for this?